# Styling and Connecting the Backbone to a Ruby Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

So I've been doing a lot of learning on Backbone, Sass, RoR, Bootstrap, etc. and I am extremely frustrated that no sources I've found (including in Tuts+ and Code School) mention any way of putting it all together...I have no clue how to style a web page if all of the contents I want in the page are being built through backbone...so if I want to click on the "About" page on a website, have all that page's Backbone contents styled correctly when appended to the DOM.

Secondly, I'm not sure how I should be creating these web pages for a website; should I be creating the whole page in Backbone and then keep that on the server until someone clicks on, for example, that "About" page and then have the whole page loaded into the view? Or am I totally misunderstanding one of the ways you can use Backbone? Along with this then, how am I supposed to communicate Backbone to a Ruby Server? just using Ajax?

I'm looking for sources and anyone who can help me understand this stuff in clear terms!

Thanks so much,

-Stu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you want to build a single page app it is important to understand each one responsibilities:

## Rails

- Create a full stack application that runs on server
- Create a consumable API
- Manage assets pipeline
- ...

## Backbone

- To manage your frontend javascript application
- Decouple data from the views using Models
- Connect an API over a RESTful JSON interface
- ...

Keep in mind this is a oversimplification of both...

Rails will handle the backend, retrieving an **API** to be consumed by Backbone. The Rails **assets pipeline** will deliver all files that Backbone needs, including the css that will style you app.

It might be somehow confusing since you will hear concepts that eventually will clash between them, like in both ends will have **Models**, **Views** and **Router**, but they will live  live independently from each other, one will work on the **server-side (Rails)** and the other on the **client-side (Backbone)**.

To give an example:

Rails would render:

```
domain
|-index.html
|-js/*.js
|-css/*.css
`-api/*.json
```

Backbone would use the DOM (index.html) and the js scripts to execute logic, append the views into the DOM and Read/Write data using ajax through the API.

Another confusing thing would be views, since Rails will generate those for you, and backbone will also have their own views, so the usual setup:

In the client-side, Backbone will be have at least the following parts:

- Router — it will orchestrate your app, binding an event a route, let's say `/#about` page and create a view and pass the respective model:

  - Model — it will request data from the API and dispatch an event when done
  - View — it will use a template to render the model data

In this case Rails would manage the page assets and provide the API, Backbone would have it own router, models, views and templates to render the page on the client-side.

This also means that the way you combine both it could be only answered regarding the project specificities, and there a lot of ways to use both.

That said, IMHO it's really important to first understand how a full Backbone app works,
then use something like [backbone-rails gem](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails), to see how both can be managed in a consistente way.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that, it cleared up a lot! I really appreciate all that info and the pointer to the backbone-rails gem.

Comment: You are more than welcome! Take also a look into [stackoverflow help](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), at some point you should mark a answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean--there's a lot of random tutorials out there for Backbone but not a lot that put it all together. To a certain extent that's just how it is, unfortunately, but I'd say once you're past learning the basics from Code School and others, the hands down best resource for how to actually build complicated apps is:

BackboneRails: http://www.backbonerails.com/

It covers the stack you're talking about mostly. The first few screencasts are free and then subsequent ones are paid but well worth it. Building on the skills I've learned from BackboneRails and I've built several fairly complicated apps that turned out great. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for that, that looks like a really great resource! I'm definitely going to check it out!

Comment: Hey Stuligan as the asker of the question you should hit the checkbox next to an answer as well as upvote the ones you agree with the people who answer get points.